# Seems that any JavaScript makes my debian laptop crash

Tags: debian, crash, segmentation-fault, javascript

I have a Dell, debian stable, laptop working with gnome environment. For several weeks Firefox crashed more and more often, resulting in mouse slows down during fews seconds, and then everything freezes, the laptop heats a lot, forcing me to hard reboot. I noticed that websites such as WhatsApp web or YouTube were specifically involved in the "crash situations".

For a week now, things have gotten much worse, any request on Google, with one window and one tab, crashes. I noticed that setting javascript.enabled=false in the settings of ff preserves from crashes.
Also, signal-desktop segfaults when launched.

I have issues finding enlightening logs, but can try.

I also tried to uninstall and reinstall all the java packages but didn't have any effect.

I ran `journalctl -f`, then waited for firefox to crash and I have uploaded the resulting log here: https://pastebin.com/4hFgtyAj.

And, probably more readable, the logs corresponding to the segfault of signal-desktop: https://pastebin.com/9b4zd2Cm.

I am also running `memtest` and I already have more than 800 errors.

Comment: Javascript is not related to Java. Please run `journalctl -f`, execute Firefox and make it crash as you said then post what logs you got using the previous command.

Comment: I missed that question sorry.

https://pastebin.com/4hFgtyAj

Everything from the middle of line 1 to line 464 is colored in red, in my terminal

Comment: Probably more readable, the logs corresponding to the segfault of signal-desktop: https://pastebin.com/9b4zd2Cm

Comment: Do you have any modifications that would classify as "Franken Debian"? (as in mixing repos like testing and stable)

Comment: No, to my knowledge the worse I have is references to non-free(-firmware) in my apt sources.list

Comment: Do you have any non Debian standard modifications? Like SELinux, extra Apparmor profiles, firejail?

Comment: No, this is the laptop I use for work, I only uses basic packages, and don't do anything messy with it. (apt search apparmor returns only one installed package, apparmor itself, the other are not on my laptop)

Comment: To rule hardware issues out: Can you run a memtest to verify that your RAM is not malfunctioning? @Boudy

Comment: You can run memtest from grub if you install the `memtest86+` package.

Comment: I'm running it, and already have 8000 errors, which is a lot I guess... It means that the laptop must be changed right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually an outdated BIOS, upgrading it solved almost everything. Noticed that there was also something wrong with `libxul.so`, everything was fine after I deleted and reinstalled it.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, `memtest` is returning a large amount of errors.

This means that something related to your system memory is wrong, most likely your RAM module. You should replace your RAM module(s) if these are removable.